Cursor moves back several words while composing messages in Outlook 365 desktop app
Just recently, the Outlook message compose interface started behaving strangely for me. As I'm typing, the visible cursor is constantly jumping back several words. When I type, the words still appear in the correct place--not where the cursor is blinking, but rather at the end of the line. But the cursor jumping around is very distracting.
Here's a brief screen-recording.
I tried disabling all COM add-ins and it made no difference.
But when I run Outlook in safe mode, the behavior disappears.
This is Windows 10 and Outlook 365 V2412 Build 16.0.18314.2, 64-bit.
Any suggestions for how to track down and eliminate the cause?

I'm sorry that I can't give a specific explanation, despite your detailed description. As far as I know, when you start safe mode, many things are disabled, such as Reading Pane, COM Add-in, Customized Toolbars and so on.  It may take some time to investigate what exactly is going wrong. You can take the following actions in turn to see if there are any changes:

Reading Pane: Clear and regenerate the navigation window for the current profile by going to Win+R>Type Outlook.exe /resetnavpane,Enter

Customized Toolbars：Back up your customizations via File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Import/Export > Export all customizations. And then, reset all customizations on the same interface.


In addition, I found some related cases, maybe you can get some ideas from them

Cursor jumped while typing in excel, word or outlook
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1299022/how-to-fix-a-cursor-that-jump-paragraphs-and-sente

Hope it helps.
